# Android Studio & libGDX - android.os.* can't implement (all android can't implement)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

today I have a problem with the Android Studio/libGDX.
I can't import any android-things, like "android.os.Handler".

Screenshot:

[image]

I hope you could help me. :))
have a nice day.

//EDIT:
Here's the Console:
[console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSenj.png)

Comment: Are you importing in `core module` ?

Comment: Hello Abhishek Aryan and first of all, thank you for your comment. Umm, yea I'm importing in the core module: Screenshot: https://image.prntscr.com/image/_NxE6kBnTo6UEh0G3LOU4w.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not able to access/import any classes of Android in `android module`

Possible reason Plugin for Android is disabled or removed/corrupt

From your Home Screen of your Android Studio

Configure -> Plugins -> Enable Plugin for Android

Then Ok, and Restart

---

**EDIT**

> From your comment you're accessing Android API in `core module`

You can't access Android APIs inside core module. Core module is generic part for all platforms.

By [interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) you can use access platform specific code.

Comment: Hey! :) - Thank you for your comment - but I already checked all Plugins: Screenshot: https://image.prntscr.com/image/vozEFCrjTjGW0ceGadlOQg.png

Comment: I don't get it. :( - How I can fix it? i read the link but it wasn't so helpful, but thank you! :)

Comment: You can't use `Handler` of android API inside `core module`

Comment: okay, but how could I delay a function? - for example: I want to debug something (text in console) 5 seconds delayed. I read this only with "Handler"

Comment: checkout [Timer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html) class of libGDX, that may be fulfil your requirement.

Comment: Hey! - Thank you! :) Now it works - But I have an another problem: my game stutters/has micro lags if I play a sound. - I did already everything: expand the sound-duration etc..